# Downloading multiple files with asyncio and tqdm

Tags: python, python-requests, download, python-asyncio, tqdm

I've got a problem. I'm trying to do an assignment for my college but I'm stuck with asyncio.
I've got a problem because the main progress bar(this one which shows how many files already were downloaded) updated only when all files are downloaded. I'm trying to fix it for a couple of hours but I don't have much experience with asyncio. Could somebody help me?

```
import requests
import random
import time
from tqdm.auto import tqdm
import asyncio

async def download(link):
    block_size = 1024
    
    response = requests.get(link[0], stream=True)
    total_size_in_bytes= int(response.headers['content-length'])
    extension = str('.'+response.headers['content-type'].split("/")[1])
    
    progress_bar = tqdm(total=total_size_in_bytes, unit='b', unit_scale=True, desc=f'FILE \"{link[1]}{extension}\"')
    
    with open(link[1]+extension, 'wb') as file:
        for data in response.iter_content(block_size):
            file.write(data)
            progress_bar.update(len(data))
    progress_bar.close()
    
    if total_size_in_bytes != 0 and progress_bar.n != total_size_in_bytes:
        print('Error!')
    else:
        print(f'File \"{link[1]}{extension}\" downloaded successfully!')
        
        
async def download_multiple(links):
    tasks = []
    
    for l in links:
        task = asyncio.create_task(download(l))
        tasks.append(task)

    progress_bar = tqdm(asyncio.as_completed(tasks), total=len(tasks), desc="DOWNLOADED: ")
    [await f for f in progress_bar]
    #progress_bar.close()


async def main():
    links = [["https://static.toiimg.com/photo/msid-67586673/67586673.jpg?3918697","jeden"],
             ["https://static.toiimg.com/photo/msid-67586673/67586673.jpg?3918697","dwa"],
             ["https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4","trzy"]]
    await (download_multiple(links))    
    
await main();
```

This is how it looks:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/to8pp.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyDB6.png)